# Why has my AIR iOs App Size Doubled?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ios7, air, flash-builder

I'm resubmitting an AIR app to the iOs store after a couple of years. It has mysteriously doubled in size. The android version comes in at just under 30 MB. The ios version is just under 60. I'm trying to figure out if this is something in my code which I should try to track down, or whether this is 'normal' behavior. Has anyone else seen this?

The only thing that I've been able to come up with is that with the advent of Retina, everything has doubled. And/or something to do with iOs7...

Thanks.

Comment: The AIR runtime adds less than 10M by default, anything beyond that is your app, code and packaged content. Publishing for retina does nothing on the app size. Check that you are not packaging extra unneeded stuff.

Comment: Universal apps (iPad and iPhone) may also increase the size of the IPA.

Comment: @JasonSturges - do universal apps double it? Also given that it is doubling in size only for iOs, any idea what I could possibly check in the code?

Comment: Did you include new images for retina displays? If you did, that would certainly increase the file size dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did go through Properties - Build Packaging - Package contents and unchecked everything I could. That removed about 4 meg.

But I was building in debug mode. Once I exported a release build, the .ipa was the same size as the .apk generated from the same code. For some reason the debug .apk is nowhere near as bloated as the debug .ipa.

Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: Debug on Android doesn't use captive runtime, it uses the AIR runtime installed on your phone (after you update your AIR SDK, it will actually ask if you want to update AIR on your device too). iOS uses what is essentially captive runtime because cross-compiling is slow. So in debug, Android doesn't include the ~9MB runtime but iOS does. There's your difference.